# Highlight text fragment selected by user

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<div>with some text<div>` and I need to highlight the text fragment selected by a user.

**I've partly implemented this:** [here is my code](http://jsfiddle.net/Greatshock/fy09jo8w/8/)

```js
thisRespondHightlightText(".container");


function thisRespondHightlightText(thisDiv){
    $(thisDiv).on("mouseup", function () {
        var selectedText = getSelectionText();
        var selectedTextRegExp = new RegExp(selectedText,"g");
        var text = $(this).text().replace(selectedTextRegExp, "<span class='highlight'>" + selectedText + "</span>");
        $(this).html(text);
    });
}

function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    }
    return text;
}
```

```css
.highlight {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
```

However, I'm stuck with solving following problems:

1. I need to highlight the exact fragment selected by user even if there a multiple matches in the text. For example, if user selects the second letter `t` in the `<div>with some text<div>`, only that `t` should be highlighted, not all of them or the first one.

[image: issue1]

2. When user select the full text, it is not highlighted, but remains selected.

[image: issue2]

3. How do I implement this for mobile? The problem is the `mouseup` event is not triggered.

Comment: have you try with [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent)

Comment: @prasanth `touchend` does not work :(

Comment: try this those events `on("touchend touchmove touchcancel mouseup"`.in my mobile its working

Comment: abot your first two problems, check out the other properties that the [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) object provides, besides `toString()`. About your 3rd problem, check out [selectionchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/selectionchange).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update

### [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) & [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) API

The following demo uses the following:

> **Selection API**
>   [`.getSelection()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection)
>   [`.getRangeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/getRangeAt)
>   **Range API**
>   [`.extractContents()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/extractContents)
>   [`.insertNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/insertNode)
>   **Miscellaneous**
>   [`.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
>   [`.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)
>   [`.ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/ctrlKey)
>   [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)
>   [`.tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName)
>   [`.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)
>   [`.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)
>   [`.createTextNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode)

Just `select` text  + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> (Mac: `select` text + <kbd>^</kbd>) and it will wrap a `<mark>` tag around the selected text. To remove the highlight `click` + <kbd>alt</kbd> (Mac: `click` + <kbd>⌥</kbd>)

---

### Demo 1

**Selection and Range API**

```js
function mark(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey) {
    var sel = document.getSelection();
    var rng = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    var cnt = rng.extractContents();
    var node = document.createElement('MARK');
    node.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    node.appendChild(cnt);
    rng.insertNode(node);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
  }
}

function unmark(e) {
  var cur = e.currentTarget;
  var tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName === 'MARK') {
    if (e.altKey) {
      var txt = tgt.textContent;
      tgt.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(txt), tgt);
    }
  }
  cur.normalize();
}

document.addEventListener('keyup', mark); // ctrl+keyup
document.addEventListener('mouseup', mark);// ctrl+mouseup
document.addEventListener('click', unmark); // alt+click
```

```css
::selection {
  background: orange
}
```

```html
<P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</P>
```

---

### [`::selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection)

Try the pseudo-element `::selection`

---

### Demo 2

```css
::selection {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</P>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did not know about this pseudo-element, it will be useful in my case for better user experience. However, I need this text to remain highlighted even after node loses the focus. So, it seems like manipulating the DOM is the only way.

Comment: Indeed DOM is the only way to get a persistent `focus`,  you could probably get something more solid by using [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) and [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) API

Comment: There's chat rooms. All we have to do is converse enough and we'll be prompted to join in....

Comment: @NikitaMarinosyan the delete function has been added. Just click + ctrl on a marked area.

Comment: I want to avoid `mark` tags nesting in case of intersection, but still to be able to apply different styles to different segments. For example, if I select `some test` in `some test phrase` it is wrapped in `mark` tags. Now, if I select `test phrase` after that, I want `some` to remain in first `mark` and the other part to be in the second `mark`. How could I achieve this?

Comment: It already does that. Highlight 2 overlapping marks then right click and inspect with the developer tools. As far as not using marks (or any inline tag), it isn't possible AFAIK. There are 2 types of nodes that we commonly access when accessing the DOM: element and text. Text has no capability to style itself  without having an element parent.

Comment: If selections intersect, then the mark tags will be nesting, while I need them to be like this: `<mark>some</mark><mark>test phrase</mark>`

Comment: That's beyond the scope of the question (actually the deletion function was as well). You can post a new question and reference this question. I think I have an idea so while you are posting the new question (if you are so inclined), I'll be working on a solution.

Comment: Posted the new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55138230/highlight-text-fragments-selected-by-user-without-nesting-tags). Also I found out the deletion doesn't work...

Comment: Ok, updated answer: `CTRL` + for `mark()` and `ALT`+ for `unmark()` . There are no more nested marks and when a mark is deleted, the textNodes are now normalized.