# Highlight text fragments selected by user without nesting tags

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a `<div>some test phrase<div>` and I need to allow user to select different fragments of text and highlight them in different colors. Also I need to allow user to delete the the highlighting (but keep the text).
I use Angular, but the solution might be in pure JS.

I've got the partial solution received in response to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55087160/highlight-text-fragment-selected-by-user):

```js
function mark() {
  var rng = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  var cnt = rng.extractContents();
  var node = document.createElement('MARK');
  node.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
  node.appendChild(cnt);
  rng.insertNode(node);
}

document.addEventListener('keyup', mark);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', mark);

function unmark(e) {
  var tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName === 'MARK') {
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
      var txt = tgt.textContent;
      tgt.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(txt), tgt);
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener('click', unmark);
```

```css
::selection {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<p>some test phrase</p>
```

However, if user selects `some test` and `test phrase` after that, the selections will intersect and the mark tags will be nesting, while I need them to be like this: `<mark>some</mark><mark>test phrase</mark>`.
So, **the general rule is: the last selection always wins, i.e. its color is always on top**. How could I achieve this for any number of selections done?

Also deletion seems not to be working from time to time and I don't know why.

### UPDATE:

Kind of implemented this, but I won't be surprised if there is a better way to do this.

[Here is the code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-segments-highlighting?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Start with cnt. If it already contains marked text you should either remark it, if it is shortened by new selection, or completely remove it, if it is contained by new range. Regard unmarking I believe you should be about to check if also the parent elem has mark.

Comment: If the selection contains multiple marks, how do I remove all of them? querySelectorAll + removeChild?

Comment: Also, what is the easiest way to “shorten” (remark) range?

Comment: There could be more options how to achieve this, maybe. I am not sure. Never done this before.

Comment: Your kinda implementation seems elegant at brief look but your highlighting elements are still nesting each other, the nesting I see in elems is very strange (let say fuzzy) and also there are spans with no text content. You can continue work on your approach nevertheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can start with this. You should thouroughly test it if it satisfy your case. Perhaps you should also refactor it to better fit you needs.

```js
function mark() {

  let selection = document.getSelection();  
  if(selection.type !== 'Range') { return;}

  let pos = window.placeOfSelections;
  
  let ranges = [];      
  let start = 0;
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(pos.childNodes, function(chD)
  {
    ranges.push([start, start + chD.textContent.length, chD.nodeName === 'MARK']);
    start += chD.textContent.length;
  });
    
  let text = pos.textContent;  
  
  let range = selection.getRangeAt(0);  
  
  let firstNode = range.startContainer;
  let lastNode = range.endContainer;
    
  selection.removeAllRanges();
    
  let firstNodeIndex = Array.prototype.findIndex.call(pos.childNodes, node => node === firstNode || node.firstChild === firstNode);
  let lastNodeIndex =  Array.prototype.findIndex.call(pos.childNodes, node => node === lastNode || node.firstChild === lastNode);
  
  let newSelectionStart = ranges[firstNodeIndex][0] + range.startOffset;  
  let newSelectionEnd = ranges[lastNodeIndex][0] + range.endOffset;  
    
  pos.innerHTML = text;  
  
  range.setStart(pos.childNodes[0], newSelectionStart);
  range.setEnd(pos.childNodes[0], newSelectionEnd);
  
  let node = document.createElement('MARK');      
  let cnt = range.extractContents();
  
  node.appendChild(cnt);
  range.insertNode(node);
      
  let marks = ranges.filter(r => r[2]);  
  while(marks.length != 0)
  {
    let startEnd = marks.shift();
    if(startEnd[0]>= newSelectionStart && startEnd[1] <= newSelectionEnd)
    {
      continue;
    }
    
    if(startEnd[0]>= newSelectionStart && startEnd[0] <= newSelectionEnd)
    {
      startEnd[0] = newSelectionEnd;
    }
    else
    if(startEnd[1]>= newSelectionStart && startEnd[1] <= newSelectionEnd)
    {
      startEnd[1] = newSelectionStart;
    }
    else
    if(startEnd[0] <=newSelectionStart && startEnd[1] >= newSelectionEnd)
    { 
      marks.push([newSelectionEnd, startEnd[1]]);
      startEnd[1] = newSelectionStart;
    }
    
    let tnStart = 0, tnEnd = 0;
    let textNode =  Array.prototype.find.call(pos.childNodes, function(tn) 
    {
      tnEnd += tn.textContent.length;
      
      if(tnStart <= startEnd[0] && startEnd[1] <= tnEnd )
      {
        return true;
      }
      
      tnStart += tn.textContent.length ;
    });
    
    range.setStart(textNode, startEnd[0] - tnStart);
    range.setEnd(textNode,  startEnd[1] - tnStart);
    
    node = document.createElement('MARK');    
    node.appendChild(range.extractContents());
    range.insertNode(node);
  }
}

window.placeOfSelections.addEventListener('keyup', mark);
window.placeOfSelections.addEventListener('mouseup', mark);

function unmark(e) {
  var tgt = e.target;
  if ((tgt.tagName === 'MARK' || (e.parentNode && e.parentNode.tagName === "MARK")) && e.ctrlKey) {
    let txt = tgt.textContent;
    tgt.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(txt), tgt);
  }
}

window.placeOfSelections.addEventListener('mousedown', unmark);
```

```css
mark {background-color: #BCE937 ;}
```

```html
<p id="placeOfSelections">some test phrase</p>
```